# Cannot find type Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument when running a toast notification from CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-runtime

I created a PowerShell script that has some XML stuff in there. In the Powershell ISE, the built-in terminal works. BUT when I ran the file from CMD, I got a error that says `New-Object : Cannot find type [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded` at line 31.

Here's the rest of the code

```
$ToastXml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$ToastXml.LoadXml($ToastTemplate.OuterXml)

$Notification = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($AppID)
$Notification.Show($ToastXml)
```

I guess it's installed built-in to the ISE, but not on windows....itself? Is there something missing in the runtime?

Comment: This looks like something from PoshNotify - https://github.com/Windos/PoshNotify.
Presumption: You are attempting to run this on a Windows 7 machine. This is not supported on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The `Windows.Data` assembly exists in a PowerShell session after invoking a method in `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager`, such as your call to `CreateToastNotifier`.

I suggest setting `$Notification` earlier in your script.

Alternatively, you can evaluate this expression:

`[Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data, ContentType=WindowsRuntime]`

(Unless you want your script to output it, you will want to capture this somehow, perhaps with the `[void]` type accelerator.)

---

Someone more familiar with the Windows Runtime may be able to explain, but for practical purposes, this works well enough. The Windows.Data assembly is not a typical assembly, nor is it found in the Global Assembly cache:

`PS> [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument].Assembly | Format-List FullName,Location,GlobalAssemblyCache,Is*`

```
FullName            : Windows.Data, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime
Location            : C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Data.winmd
GlobalAssemblyCache : False
IsDynamic           : False
IsFullyTrusted      : True
```

Comment: `GetTemplateContent` also works.

Comment: One other thing I observed when learning this: after making the call, all existing and subsequent PowerShell tabs in the same PowerShell ISE window will be able to resolve the type! (Not to be confused with the tabs for files themselves.)

Comment: I have found many scripts for toast notifications which begin `[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null`, but this seems to not be necessary (at least on a handful of machines I tried: Windows 10, 11, Server).

Comment: (So the full story is: in an ISE Window I at some point invoked a `ToastNotificationManager` method. Subsequent `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument` references in that ISE window succeeded. I then tried to run my new script a non-ISE context and encountered your same error. I then opened a new ISE window and noticed that the script *still* did not work. This is likely what happened to you as well.)